An example of a nested decreasing sequence of bounded closed sets from l_2 with empty intersection
I am trying to provide an example of a nested decreasing sequence of bounded closed sets from $l_2$ with empty intersection.
I've tried different variants with bounded coordinates, like this: $$A_n = \{(x_1, x_2, \dots) \in l_2 | \sum_{k}{x_k^2} = 1, |x_k| \leq \frac{1}{n}\}$$ (or $\sum_k{x_k^2} \leq 1$), but as I understand, such kind of examples have problems with being closed, because they don't contain its limit point $(0, 0, \dots)$.
Where am I missing something or maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction?

These sets are closed. The origin is a weak limit point, so no problem here.
